# Change permissions of a folder with cronjob

Tags: mac, finder, permission, cron

I have a scanner that can "save to folder" only with FTP or CIFS protocols.

I managed to set it up with CIFS to save the file to a shared folder on a Mac, however although the folder has read/write permissions to all users, when the file is written to the folder it only has read/write permissions to the user that created it (scan). This means even the local user can't open the file unless we change the permissions of the file. Applying the permissions to "enclosed items" solves the issue until a new scan is made.
I don't know how to create a cronjob so that permissions are changed every minute.
Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Thanks!
Miguel

Comment: You don't need `cron` for that

Comment: Could you explain how to do it?

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to the questions linked from the yellow box at the top of your question.